# How to write a "&" in button text in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

This looks simple but I have not found any documentation. Tried with `&&`, which does not work. Want a button like this:

```
Button1=wx.Button(self, 5, "abc&abc", (130, 230))
```

Comment: Are you sure that double ampersand `&&` doesn't appear as a single? All the hits I've found suggest that it does.

Comment: i have checked not working ..

Comment: my quetion should be how to write & in button text when displaying it in click event of menubar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me with this:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent,title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(200,-1))
    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.buttons = [
      wx.Button(self,-1,"Button &One"),
      wx.Button(self,-1,"Button &&Two"),
    ]
    for btn in self.buttons:
      self.sizer.Add(btn,1,wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.sizer.Fit(self)
    self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None,"Hello Ampersand")
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working MattH but my problem is actually i was showing button in click event of menubar at that time && not works..check out below code...what should be done in such a case

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent,title):     
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(699, 570))     

    fileMenu= wx.Menu()
    folder=wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, 1, "&Start","Click here to start..")

    fileMenu.AppendItem(folder)
    about = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, 2, '&About',"Test")

    fileMenu.AppendItem(about)
    quit = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, 3, '&Quit',"Terminate the program")

    fileMenu.AppendItem(quit)
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu,"&File")    
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ShowButton, folder)

    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)     
    pndSummaryButton = wx.Button(self, 3, "Button &&Two", (130, 146))
    pndSummaryButton.name="pndSummary"

    self.printArea2 = wx.TextCtrl(self,pos = (290, 146), size = (255, 25),style = wx.TE_READONLY)
    pndSummaryButton.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL,wx.LIGHT))
    self.printArea2.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL,wx.LIGHT))
    pndSummaryButton.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(153,0,0))
    pndSummaryButton.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
    pndSummaryButton.SetSize(pndSummaryButton.GetBestSize())

    self.Show()  

  def ShowButton(self,event):
    pndSummaryButton = wx.Button(self, 3, "Button &&Two", (130, 176))
    pndSummaryButton.name="pndSummary1"
    self.printArea2 = wx.TextCtrl(self,pos = (290, 176), size = (255, 25),style = wx.TE_READONLY)
    pndSummaryButton.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL,wx.LIGHT))
    self.printArea2.SetFont(wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL,wx.LIGHT))
    pndSummaryButton.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(153,0,0))
    pndSummaryButton.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
    pndSummaryButton.SetSize(pndSummaryButton.GetBestSize())

app = wx.App(False) 
frame = MainWindow(None,"Hello Ampersand") 
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: @sagar: It's helpful to post functioning, correctly formatted code. Your example works fine for me. After clicking on "Start", a second button appears as `Button &Two`.

Comment: its not working at my side..after clicking on frame first button also tunrs to Button Two.

Comment: same code as above..using os is windows 7.. python version is 2.5  wx  library is wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.11.0-py25

Comment: its working only if i didnot set the button colour ie foreground and BackGroundcolor ..is anybody able to set the color and with & in button text same as above code..please mention ur wx version and os version if you able to do so..

Comment: On Windows setting button colors puts it in "owner drawn" mode, so it is not being drawn by the native widget code.  There is probably a bug in the wx code that is drawing the label, or at least the && is not being handled properly by that code.  Please create a ticket for this on trac.wxwidgets.org with all the relevant details.